# Is it possible to get non-lifetime metrics for page posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I was trying to get post insights using https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/post_id/insights, but no matter what I set the period, since and until query parameters, I am always getting lifetime metrics.  Is there a way to get day metrics for each post?

Specific example: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/20767777944_10153119015042945/insights/?access_token=TOKEN&period=day&since=2015-08-23&until=2015-08-23

Comment: Can you edit the question and add which concrete API calls (without your access token) you have made?

Comment: Same prolem here with the API calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957049/facebook-insights-lifetime-metric-missing-end-date